# Const vs protected static readonly

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a wrapper class which encapsulates a piece of information that needs to be transmitted as a byte array.

In that way, the class encapsulates the necessary header (with fields like DATA_LENGTH or MESSAGE_TYPE) into the corresponding byte positions. For that I want to define positions and length in constants, for example:

```
HEADER_DATA_LENGTH_IX = 0;
HEADER_DATA_LENGTH_LENGTH = 2;
```

which means DATA_LENGTH starts at 0 and takes two bytes.

but so far I'm struggling with making them constants or static readonly fields. Const cannot be protected, therefore I won't be able to derive a new class and change the constants if a use them, on the other way I might declare new constants in the derived class and the use them.

What will be your approach?

Comment: What technology is this? .Net? Java?

Comment: The tag wasn't ther when I first post the answer, sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the value of these params in a derived class, you can make them [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) and change them in the constructor of the derived class

I wouldn't make them [const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) anyhow, because they're not...

Comment: If you want to set the value in a derived class, you don't want it to be static, as this can only be set in the static constructor

Answer (score 4):

The basic difference is when the variable is initialized.  'readonly' is set at initialization, or in the contructor, while 'const' is set at compile time.

I think the big decision is if you want to inherit the class and override the value.  If you do, go readonly.  Otherwise I don't think it really matters.

readonly C#ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx

const C# ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Create an inner class with the constants. The deriving classes can then later override the inner class and change the constants as necessary.

e.g. base class:

```
public class Stuff
{
  public class HeaderInformation
  {
    public const int HEADER_DATA_LENGTH_IX = 0;
    public const int  HEADER_DATA_LENGTH_LENGTH = 2;
  }
}
```

Then the derived class can do this:

```
public class DerivedStuff : Stuff
{
  public new class HeaderInformation : Stuff.HeaderInformation
  {
    public new const int HEADER_DATA_LENGTH_IX = 10;
  }
}
```

This way, you have flexibility. In `DerivedStuff`, the HeaderInformation class has all of the constants in the base `Stuff.HeaderInformation` class, but can change any of them, or keep the ones it has.

Answer (score 1):

This exact question is answered by [the official c# faq on msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/12/03/274791.aspx)

Comment: Can you insert the Q&A in your answer to prevent link rot?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't make these constant because they simply aren't constants. When declaring something as const you should ask yourself: can this change? Your message lengths might change one day, so they are better to be made readonly.

Comment: They can't change, well they might but then the idea is to derive a new class to handle the changes, therefore, for the class life the values will hold, will be constant and are only there to avoid "magic numbers"